# How to send an array via post in cURL so that it can be store in Database directly as it is

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am using CI in which i am sending an array via post.

I am converting it in a string like

```
$post_string= "";
foreach ($post_value as $k=>$v){
    $post_string = $post_string.$k.'='.$v.'&';
}
$post_string = rtrim($post_string, "&");
$post_string = trim($post_string, "&");
```

Now i am passing it in curl request

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

like this.
I want save it into database then again i have to make it an array so that i can send it it 
to model.

If a array contains much elements then this method gone to lengthy.

Is there any way to send this array directly via post.?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly via post"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$json = json_encode($post_value);

$ch = curl_init('http://put_the_url_here');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then by which name i access this array.
I mean 
$this->post('?');

Comment: just `$this->input->post();` don't put anything inside `()`

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize array and then pass.. later.. unserialize when you want it in an array.